# One jQuery function is messing with the CSS of another

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm just getting started with learning jQuery, and I'm having a small CSS issue. Please refer to:

http://www.paulgrantdesign.com/test77/photography/examples.php
and and .../examples2.php

In the first example, the photo gallery looks the way I want it to, and the part of the gallery in question is the thumbnails. You can see that the thumbnails are exactly scaled-down versions of the full image. In the second example, I've incorporated an expand/collapse toggle that opens the gallery when you click the link. The expanding is working just fine, but it's causing the thumbnails to neither be sized nor placed properly.

Does someone know how to fix this? Thanks!!

EDIT: Someone requested some code. I don't want to add too much, so here's what I'm doing:
In my head, I of course have the include of the photo gallery js, which is called PikaChoose. You can see the .js file at http://www.paulgrantdesign.com/test77/photography/albumtest/jquery.pikachoose.js

My expand/collapse code is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".gallery").hide();
  //jQuery(".collapse").hide();
  //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
  jQuery(".title").click(function()
  {
jQuery(this).next(".gallery").slideToggle(500);
  });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".collapse").click(function()
   {
   jQuery(this).parent(".gallery").slideToggle(500);
  });
});
```

Comment: You need to provide some actual code

Comment: I kind of like the 2nd one.  They look like they are peeking over the edge of something.

Comment: That won't be the case for all images in all galleries.

Comment: Do you set the thumbnail image size directly anywhere? Because I'm noticing that in the examples.php the size is 90x60 and in the examples2.php it's 150x100

Comment: nope. it sets automatically by the plugin. I described solution in my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a bug in gallery. When it's initialized in the element with `display:none` the thumbnails image size is bigger. To fix it probably you need to initialize the gallery in callback.

```
jQuery(".collapse").click(function () {
        jQuery(this).parent(".gallery").slideToggle(500, function () {
            $("#pikame").PikaChoose({ carousel: true, carouselVertical: true });
        });
    });
```

I steal your code a little :)

Comment: Sorry - like I said, I'm new to jQuery. Where is it initialized with display:none?

Comment: It's you set on the div with class `gallery`. You don't need to remove it. Just init the gallery like I mentioned. (it's parts from your page and probably will work)

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help, but I'm not really understanding the solution. Could you spell out a bit more code please? I'm a bit lost for what you'd like me to try. The .collapse div is just an alternative to re-clicking the .title div. When you click the .title div in my code, it toggles between expanding and collapsing the next .gallery div. The .collapse div and will say something like "Hide this gallery" and will go inside the .gallery div and collapse its parent.

Comment: look. You have initialization of `PikaChoose...` on the `$(document).ready` - remove it! :) The click on item with class `jQuery(".collapse").click...` replace with my code. And that's it.

Comment: I got it. I moved your solution up a line under the .gallery slideToggle. That did the trick, though I don't really know why. Can you explain to me what happened when we moved that line up into the previous function?

Comment: You can take a look with firebug just after page loading that your div with class 'gallery' have style `display:none` that is the problem I describe in the ansver

Comment: Sure, we moved initialization of gallery after displaying the gallery div from the document loading. In this case gallery will initialize in the already showed div, not in hidden. That's the trick. :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try hiding the section with the image gallery [after the document has loaded](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). That could be a potential cause of the problem. As a side note, maybe consider using jQuery's [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) or [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) for the image that's displayed in that section.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    <your code to hide the that section>
});
```

Comment: In the functioning version, it does start hidden.

Comment: does it? When I opened the first example (in chrome at least) the link does nothing and the bottom section is displayed.

Comment: Yes, in the first example, I broke the expand/collapse on purpose to show how the thumbnails are supposed to look. The expand/collapse works in the second example, and the div starts hidden, but the thumbnails are messed.

Comment: ok sorry, is anything loaded from an ajax call? when are the images physically loaded. It also seems that there are multiple instances of the $(document).ready() function being created? Why not combine them all into one?

Comment: Definitely no AJAX. Like I said, I'm totally new to jQuery - I'll try to get to AJAX eventually, but not today :) It seems to me that the images should be loaded with the main body of the website, because the images are just a simple unordered list. 

I've tried to combine them all into one, but being so new to jQuery, I don't know how to keep it in syntax. It keeps breaking when I try to combine things. I'd appreciate some help if you can.

Comment: Got it with a suggestion from Samich. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I just didn't know, for a small subset of images that works well. I didn't know if they were uploaded and dynamically loaded. Can I ask why are there multiple $(document).ready() functions in your code, instead of combining them all into one?

Comment: I'd really appreciate some help with that if you're willing. I'd love some help making the code tidier if you're willing.

Comment: What would you like help with?

Comment: I tried a few different ways to combine everything that needed to be under the document.ready() function into one, but it just breaks things, and I don't know how to troubleshoot what's breaking. I guess I just need to know what can be combined and how.

Comment: What broke? I mean everything in a document ready function in your code should be able to be within the same document ready function.